# How to port a feature branch from an original repo to a new repo created with `git subtree`

Tags: git

Imagine this git history:

```
    /-----/------- feature
---o-----o-----x   oldrepo/master
               *-- newrepo/master
  Jun   Jul   Sep
```

I cut a feature branch from master in June, working on it over the summer.
In September, we extracted part of the file tree on master and turned it into its own repo (this new repo contains all the files that are part of my feature, and more). We used `git subtree`, so the new repo has all the original history for the files that were moved. That set of files was then `git rm`ed in the old repo.

Now I want to somehow move my feature branch to the new repo, so that it can eventually land in the new repo's master branch. The feature branch in the old repo can die afterward.

Using `git log`, I've identified 41 commits that matter. One of them, in the middle, is me merging master back up into my feature so I don't fall behind; it includes an enormous numebr of commits to files that are not part of the new repo (being outside the subtree).

I've tried using `git format-patch` to generate patches for the 40 commits that I care about, but `git am commit01.patch` fails in the new repo for two reasons (or at least, two I can identify):

1. the paths in the patch files are wrong, since they were created in a repo whose filesystem is a superset of the filesystem in the new repo
2. genuine (but solveable) merge conflict arising from changes made to a feature-related file since the last time I merged up from master into my feature

I was able to solve the first problem by doing some batch find/replace work on the patch files, since the path translation is straightforward. But `git am` predicably doesn't like that I'm trying to replay changes onto a file that's evolved since those changes were recorded.

I'm kind of stuck for how to proceed.

Ideally, I would like to avoid re-doing the work. That said, the patch files obviously provide enough info for me to do so if necessary.

Any help is very much appreciated.